# How to fit a long text file field into a listbox?

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a program that is reading the information for recipes from a text file. I have the text file structured in a way that the list of instructions for each recipe are combined into one field of the text file. However, when I try to display the instructions into a listbox, it displays as one long line, and you can't see the full set of instructions. Is there anyway to manipulate that single field of the text file to continue onto the next line of the listbox when the text fills the space? I've included a picture of my code for displaying other elements of the text file line.

**code**

[image]

Here is what the sample field says in my text file:
In a pan sauté the shallots in olive oil. Add the brussel sprouts. Sauté until vibrant green. Add chopped bacon and balsamic vinegar if desired.

Once again, I just need help on how to get that giant field to fit to my text box. Here is a picture of my form during runtime currently. Thank you!

**vb form**

[image]

Comment: You need to post your code as text, not images. Anyway, have you considered a RichTextBox instead of a ListBox, to show the instructions? A RTB so you can change the color of sections of text and *style* it. The units of time should be a parameter, not an hardcoded string.

Comment: Please do not post code as an image. You need to post it as text and format as code. A cookbook was my very first coding project. I was using Borland's Paradox. I think you are going to find that a database will be much easier to use than text files. There are several free ones available.

Answer (score 0):

You've to control the drawing yourself.

From [DrawMode docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.drawmode?view=netframework-4.8), `OwnerDrawVariable`:

> All the elements in the control are drawn manually and can differ in size.

Now, I'm setting the ItemHeight in MeasureItem event, and drawing the text in DrawItem event.

```vb
Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
    yourListBox.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable
    MyBase.OnLoad(e)
End Sub

Private Sub yourListBox_MeasureItem(sender As Object, e As MeasureItemEventArgs) Handles yourListBox.MeasureItem
    e.ItemHeight = e.Graphics.MeasureString(yourListBox.Items(e.Index).ToString(), yourListBox.Font, yourListBox.Width).Height + 10
End Sub

Private Sub yourListBox_DrawItem(sender As Object, e As DrawItemEventArgs) Handles yourListBox.DrawItem
    If e.Index < 0 Then Return
    e.DrawBackground()
    e.Graphics.DrawString(yourListBox.Items(e.Index).ToString(), yourListBox.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds)
End Sub
```